# why the query of mysqli is not inserting values into database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried  simple code but instead of inserting value into database table,its triggering the javascript alert of insertion failed I tried    everything still cant insert the value into the table. I am new to mysqli.

```
        <?php       
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database')or die(mysqli_error($con));

      // Check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
         }
        else
         {
           echo "Your Database is connected , No issues there..";

         }
             $Name = $_POST['Name'];
              $q =mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO  tablename(Field_Name) VALUES ('$Name')")or die(mysqli_error($con));

          echo $q;

       if($q)
      {

        header("Location:newpage.php");

        }
         else
          {      
             ?>
               <script>alert('insertion failed');</script>

           <?php
             } 

             mysqli_close($con);
               }

          ?>
```

Comment: What's the field name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
$q =mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO  tablename(Field_Name) VALUES ('$Name')"or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

You seem to be missing a closing bracket.

```
$q =mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO  tablename(Field_Name) VALUES ('$Name')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

If you continue to have errors, make sure your

- Table name is correct
- Your fields are correct

I also suggest you change

```
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
```

to

```
$Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Name']);
```

Comment: srry that was my typing mistake bracket is there still it doesnt wrk

Comment: Run `echo mysqli_error($con);` after your query to see the error.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Name']); this wrkd for now thanks

Comment: It may have been because your input was breaking your query. Make sure you always escape strings or use prepared statements :)